# Creating on/off button in react

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I am making a button that is going to say "disable" when its on and "enable" when its off. how do I do that in react?? I have tried to make it but I have no idea where to even start, is there some syntax im missing?

Comment: Can you provide some code of your attemps ?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what did you try and why do you think there's syntax missing?

Answer (score 0):

The code below does the job of displaying the button text based on a state.
Inside the `useState()` hook you can specify the initial state.
On the button's click event the state will be reversed to toggle between `true` and `false`

```
const customButton = () => {
 const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

 return (
  <button 
    onClick={() => setEnabled(!enabled)}>
    {enabled ? "disable" : "enable"}
  </button>
 );
}
```